# No events were emitted - Exchanging ERC721 Tokens

Tags: truffle-test, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

Function to exchange ERC721 Tokens between two addresses. I am implementing this on truffle and openzeppelin 2.10. Two different tokens should be exchanged between two addresses.

Here's my contract function for exchanging ERC721 tokens:

```solidity
function exchangeStars(uint256 token1, uint256 token2, address starOwner2) public {
    require(this.ownerOf(token1) == msg.sender);

    transferFrom(msg.sender, starOwner2, token1);
    transferFrom(starOwner2, msg.sender, token2);
}
```

This is the test I am writing for creating Tokens and exchanging between two addresses.

```js
describe('Exchange Stars', () =>  {
  let token1 = 101;
  let token2 = 202;

  it('User 1 creates Star', async() => {
    await this.contract.createStar(starName, story, ra, dec, mag, token1, { from: account1 });
    assert.equal(await this.contract.ownerOf.call(token1), account1);
  });

  it('User 2 creates Star', async() => {
    await this.contract.createStar(starName2, story, ra, dec, mag, token2, { from: account2 });
    assert.equal(await this.contract.ownerOf.call(token2), account2);
  });

  it('Users exchange Stars', async() => {
    await this.contract.exchangeStars(token1, token2, account2);
    assert.equal(await this.contract.ownerOf.call(token2), account2);
    console.log(await this.contract.ownerOf.call(token2));
  });

});
```

Here's the result for my tests:

> ```
> Exchange Stars
>   √ User 1 creates Star (129ms)
>   √ User 2 creates Star (116ms)
>   1) Users exchange Stars
> > No events were emitted
> ```

Comment: Is that the entire output of your tests? It seems like the third test failed, but there's usually more output on how the test failed.